# PyTorch tensors have same value after being added to a list

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, gradient

While learning gradients and optimizing the process by Pytorch, I wanted to figure out the change of loss function values vs weights values with the graph. While I tried to graph, I used both `numpy` and `torch`, because I wanted to compare. During to store list of grad. and loss function values.
It works at numpy:

```py
def gradient(x,y, y_predicted):
  return np.dot(2*x, y_predicted-y).mean() 

dw = gradient(x,y,y_pred)
dw_list.append(dw)
```

`[-120.0, -112.8, -106.032, -99.67008, -93.68988, -88.06848, -82.78437, -77.81731, -73.14827, -68.75938]`

It doesn't works at torch:

```
  for epoch in range(n_iters):
    # prediction = forward pass
    y_pred = forward(x)
    
    # loss
    l = loss(y, y_pred)
    loss_list.append(l)
    print('loss')
    print(l_list)
    # gradients = backward pass
    l.backward()  # calculate w.grad = dl/dw   and cumulative 
    
    # update weights
    with torch.no_grad():
        w -= learning_rate * w.grad
    print(f'w.grad before zero setting = {w.grad}')
    dw_list.append(w.grad) 
    print(dw_list)
    #print(f'w.grad before zero setting = {w.grad}')
    # zero gradients
    w.grad.zero_()
```

`[tensor(-6.9485), tensor(-6.9485), tensor(-6.9485), tensor(-6.9485), tensor(-6.9485), tensor(-6.9485), tensor(-6.9485), tensor(-6.9485), tensor(-6.9485), tensor(-6.9485)]`

Why `dw_list.append(dw)` works at numpy, but `dw_list.append(w.grad)` does not work at torch?

Why only the new value of grad had been filled up the whole array at each iter. at torch tensor?

Comment: In the first case `mean()` returns a scalar.  In the second evidently `w.grad` is not a scalar.  List append isn't doing anything different.

Comment: Correct the indentation.  Show the initialization of the lists.

Comment: Please post full runnable examples (including import, sample data etc) - it makes it much easier to figure out the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`w.grad` is a tensor; it (the **same** tensor) is appended to the list at each iteration, so the list contains copies of the same tensor, not copies of its **value** at each point in time as you'd probably intend.

The standard way of handling this is to use:

```
dw_list.append(w.grad.detach().cpu().numpy())
```

Please have a look at this discussion for why detach() is necessary:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/should-it-really-be-necessary-to-do-var-detach-cpu-numpy/35489/6

By contrast, np.mean() returns a *new* python float object every time it is called, and so the values are different at the end.  The list append() is not doing anything different in the two cases.

P.S. I think this would also work:

```
dw_list.append(w.grad.clone())
```

however it would keep the cloned tensors in the graph (and on the gpu, if the originals were on the gpu).  That may or may not be what you want.